# React final form - How to untouch field or hide error on onBlue

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

How to hide error on onBlur? I have an error validation before submitting, but I want to hide the error on onBlue. This is how I use form. I tried to change meta, but no results. Thank you.

```
 <Form
        initialValues={{ search }}
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        render={({ handleSubmit }) => (
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Field name="search" validate={composeValidators(required, minLength)}>
              {({ input, meta }) => (
                <div>
                  <SearchInputDumb {...input} submitSearch={handleSubmit}/>
                  {meta.error && meta.touched && (
                    <SearchFieldFooter>
                      <SearchStyledTipIcon />
                      <span>{meta.error}</span>
                    </SearchFieldFooter>
                  )}
                </div>
              )}
            </Field>
          </form>
        )}
      />
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a isInputFocused state and make the error hide with that. In your SearchInputDumb component you could implement a onFocus/onBlur methods to change the isInoputFocused state

Comment: Thank you. I will try it now.